# angular appliying css from containing component

Tags: css, angular

I have a basic component that is been reused in many places. every place needs to give its own style to this component.
App component:

HTML

```
<p>
  The <b>widgets-input</b> component bellow with some css from AppComponent <br />
  <widgets-input></widgets-input>
</p>
```

CSS

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 540px;
  height: 52px;
}
```

The styles wont be applied on `widgets-input`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n3xgmx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: You can pass to the component an `input` (IE: mode). In the `widgets-component` you can assign with `ngStyle` & `ngClass` a specify class/style based on the input `mode`

Comment: You want to style the child from the parents' stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `::ng-deep`:

```
::ng-deep input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 540px;
  height: 42px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

**PS:** Although it'll be deprecated, there is no alternative for now, as [**official doc mentioned**](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep):

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to style childs, you have to use ng-deep :

```
:host::ng-deep widgets-input input{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 540px;
  height: 42px;
  border: solid 1px red; 
}
```